# Handling dynamically created control?

Tags: c#

I'm writing simple web browser in c#. For multi tab functionality I added tabcontrol and placed webbrowser1 in it.  I use toolstripbutton to dynamically add tabpages , webbrowsers (and handle its events with webbrowser1 events):

```
        TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabpage);
        WebBrowser webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webbrowser.Parent = tabpage;
        webbrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webbrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");
        webbrowser.DocumentTitleChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentTitleChanged);
        webbrowser.StatusTextChanged += new EventHandler(webBrowser1_StatusTextChanged);
        webbrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webbrowser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        webbrowser.Navigated += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_Navigated);
        webbrowser.Navigating += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_Navigating);
        webbrowser.ProgressChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_ProgressChanged);
```

my issue is I cant handle them properly because I wrote code for webbrowser1 and dont know how to call dynamically created object. I wrote this:

```
    private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
        {
            if (e.GetType() == typeof(WebBrowser))
            {
                WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                    web.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
            }
        }

    }
```

but it doesn't work at all ( even for webbrowser1). How should I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: e is never equal to type WebBrowser it is an event, also if it was you create a new instance of the WebBrowser instead of creating an instance of the type given by the event handler.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to do `sender.GetType()`? `if (sender is WebBrowser)` would be even better.

Comment: You are also creating a new `WebBrowser` object in your event handler, and then displaying the page in that new `WebBrowser` rather than using the one you already have loaded in your tab so the page you navigate to is never displayed to the user.  You are also creating the `WebBrowser` for every keystroke and dropping most of them on the floor to be cleaned up later.

Comment: @TimonPost I used about same code to find checked radiobutton in groupbox and modified it(I thought it would work). I dont have any other idea.

Comment: @CodyGray tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @StevenRogers You may have a code with the same lookalike - but you can **never** get a control instance out of the event argument

Comment: Thanks I solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are intending to do something like this:

```
private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        var web = c as WebBrowser;
        if (c != null && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            web.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

You are looping through the controls in your `TabControl`, you need to find the one that is a `WebBrowser`.  Once you have that control, then you want to perform the navigation with that particular instance of a `WebBrowser` instead of creating a new browser.  I don't know what other code you have for the key handler, but if you are only performing an action on enter, I would revise this code to check for that first and only walk the collection when I actually need to.  Like this:

```
private void toolStripTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter) return;

    foreach (Control c in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        var web = c as WebBrowser;
        if (c != null)
        {
            web.Navigate(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```